# Is there an easier way?

Tags: ruby

```
class Store
  def check_inventory
    @inventory ||= []
    @inventory.each { ... }
  end
end
```

Can the lines with the instance variables on them be turned into a one-liner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Yes!! There is always a cool hack in Ruby!

---

```
class Store
  def check_inventory
    @inventory.to_a.each { ... }
  end
end
```

The reason this works is Cool Ruby Feature number 9,123: as it happens, `NilClass` implements a `#to_a` method that returns `[]`!  How awesome is that?!

```
edtq ross$ irb --prompt-mode simple
>> nil.to_a
=> []
>> @this_does_not_exist.to_a
=> []
```

Comment: =O Ruby never ceases to amaze.

Comment: Off-topic though :) I'm just amused there's actually a count of Ruby Feature? This one is 9,123th feature? - Java guy here

Comment: Yes, but the Ruby camp is divided between the ones that number features from 0 and those that started at 1.  It's like the Hatfield's and the McCoy's at RailsConf every year...

Answer (score 4):

[DigitalRoss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577588/is-there-an-easier-way/4577614#4577614) is *almost* the same, but it will *never* change `@inventory`; your code will ensure that `@inventory` is always an array.  If you need that behavior, you can just straightforwardly combine the two lines:

```
class Store
  def check_inventory
    (@inventory ||= []).each { ... }
  end
end
```

Comment: If the OP prefers to keep side effects to a minimum: (@inventory || []).each { ... }

Comment: @tokland: In that case, I'd just use [DigitalRoss's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577588/is-there-an-easier-way/4577614#4577614) with `.to_a`.